# The value in cython array is changed randomly

Tags: python, cython

Here is my cython code.

`self.point_index_array` attribute is array whose values increase by 1 from 0.

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .....]

The values are normal when first declared, but when the array is accessed from another function, the values of the first four elements are automatically changed.

python and cython version

- Python 3.9.13
- Cython 0.29.34

Here is my sudo code

```
cdef class KdTree:
    cdef uint32_t* point_index_array

    def __cinit__(KdTree self):
        self.point_index_array = NULL

    def __init__(KdTree self, 
                 np.ndarray points not None, 
                 int num_of_leaf=16):
        cdef np.ndarray[uint32_t, ndim=1] point_index_list
        point_index = np.arange(0, self.num_of_points, dtype=np.uint32)
        point_index_list = np.ascontiguousarray(point_index.ravel(), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.point_index_array = <uint32_t*>point_index_list.data
    
        # kdtree...

        # its normal
        self.print_index_array()

    def print_index_array(self):
        for index in range(10):
          print(f"index {index} => {self.point_index_array[index]}")


    def neighbor_search(self, float distance):
        # values in self.point_index_array are changed 
        self.print_index_array()
```

normal output is (`__init__`)

> index 0 => 390
> index 1 => 469
> index 2 => 493
> index 3 => 492
> index 4 => 396
> index 5 => 490
> index 6 => 397
> index 7 => 117
> index 8 => 484
> index 9 => 9

abnormal output is (`neighbor_search`)

> index 0 => 1171518192
> index 1 => 504
> index 2 => 1174758304
> index 3 => 504
> index 4 => 396
> index 5 => 490
> index 6 => 397
> index 7 => 117
> index 8 => 484
> index 9 => 9

I don't understand why this happens at all.

Could you let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know Cython so this might be a dumb question, but what stops the locally-scoped `point_index_list` being garbage collected after `__init__` ends?

Comment: @slothrop Yes - that's what's happening

Comment: @slothrop i undertood that c pointer in cython do not become CG and must be freed directly. And save it in class attribute. Of course i could be wrong...

Comment: I think that's the case if you explicitly allocated the memory using `malloc`, but not if you get a pointer to an existing Python-managed object.

Comment: @slothrop oh.. you are right. thanks. It is working when i save "point_index_list" variable in class attribute. I put the modified code in the body!

Comment: could there be an overflow with `uint32_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@slothrop thanks for your appreciate!

"point_index_list" variable is python object in previous code, so it was removed by GC.

so, i save this object to class attribute.

```
cdef class KdTree:
  cdef uint32_t* point_index_array
  cdef readonly np.ndarray point_index_list

  def __init__(KdTree self, 
                np.ndarray points not None, 
                int num_of_leaf=16):

    point_index = np.arange(0, self.num_of_points, dtype=np.uint32)

    # this code will prevent CG of point_index_list
    self.point_index_list = np.ascontiguousarray(point_index.ravel(), dtype=np.uint32)
    self.point_index_array = <uint32_t*>self.point_index_list.data
```